# Read default block size of HDFS using Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to read this default block size value from `hdfs-site.xml` using a java program ? Can anyone help in this ?

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>134217728</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: The following code provides a default block size. But it reports me method deprecated.Is this a correct way or we have any other code.

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
long defaultsize = fs.getDefaultBlockSize();
System.out.println("Default block size : " + defaultsize );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is better option I found rather I reading the default block size from HDFS-SITE XML.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

Configuration cconf = fs.getConf();
String block = cconf.get("dfs.blocksize");
long dsize = Long.parseLong(block);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `get` method of `Configuration` to get that parameter (or any other). You first need to add the resource, just as you did in the comment you posted, and then get the parameter:

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
System.out.println(conf.get("dfs.blocksize"));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes , it worked. But I should continue to use Configuration conf = new Configuration();